# File Explorer in Android Studio 1.5.1

Tags: android, android-studio

Ive been searching for this for almost an hour and diferrent searches result said that it is present in Android Monitor but I cant find any. This is my android monitor.

[image]

Thanks!

By the way, im using an actual device not an emulator

Comment: That is logcat, not a file explorer

Comment: yes but that is android monitor. I cant see DDMS.

Comment: @JCFrane You enabled the developer mode in device?

Comment: yes, I already run my application on my device.

Comment: Is you android device monitor showing you device?

Comment: yes, it actually logging errors and stuffs on my logcat. And when I run my app its state is online.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this? I have the same issue.

Comment: They closed it how can we have solution?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED:**

Seems like that `File Explorer` in your below toolbar on main `Android Studio` *is not available*.

`Goto Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor` and you'll see something like this: (***Tested with - Real Device***)

That is available in your `DDMS`.

[image]

Comment: i cant really find that =(

Comment: @JCFrane - See my updated answer.if you couldn't find it, put a screenshot from your Android Device monitor from `Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor`. it's working.